# WPF - can't get resource file

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, embedded-resource

I have file animaha135.gif in /Images folder, set "Build Action" as "Embedded Resource" or "Resources", I want to get this image to bitmap:

```
            var image = new BitmapImage();
            image.BeginInit();
            image.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/animaha135.gif");
            image.EndInit();
```

but it does not work:

> Cannot locate resource 'images/animaha135.gif'.

what I do incorrectly?

---

solved this problem. Name of assembly was another than name of project. I set the same and my first code works

Answer (score 2):

Don t build as "Embedded Resource". Build as "Resource". -> worked for me

EDIT:

use this to create your uri:

```
protected static Uri GetUri(string filename, Type type)
{
    Assembly assembly = type.Assembly;
    string assemblyName = assembly.ToString().Split(',')[0];
    string uriString = String.Format("pack://application:,,,/{0};component/{1}",
        assemblyName, filename);
    return new Uri(uriString);
}
```

I used this for custom shadereffects

Comment: Can you tell a bit more about the folder structure of your application? Go to the mainwindow as example and create a image. Use the Propertygrid and edit the source property. It will generate your uri

Comment: what should I pass to "type" parameter?

Comment: I have root folder named "Images" and file "animaha135.gif" inside this folder

Answer (score 0):

If you use embeed resources, you need read assembly maniffest

```
      private void LoadImg()
    {

       //x is name of <Image name="x"/>
       x.Source = GetResourceTextFile(GetResourcePath("Images/animaha135.gif"));


    }


    private string GetResourcePath(string path)
    {
        return path.Replace("/", ".");
    }


    public BitmapFrame GetResourceTextFile(string filename)
    {

        string result = string.Empty;

        using (Stream stream = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(String.Format("{0}.{1}",this.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Name,filename)))
        {
            BitmapFrame bmp = BitmapFrame.Create(stream);
            return bmp;
        }

    }
```

Other solution (return Bitmap):

```
 //Use   BitmapImage bitmap = GetResourceTextFile(GetResourcePath("Images/animaha135.gif"));


    public BitmapImage GetResourceTextFile(string filename)
    {

        string result = string.Empty;

        using (Stream stream = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(String.Format("{0}.{1}",this.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Name,filename)))
        {

            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.BeginInit();
            bi.StreamSource = stream;
            bi.EndInit();

            return bi;
        }

    }
```

Note: Embed resources replace  path =>  / by .